# Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables returns unexpected path in IIS

Tags: c#, iis-10

```
var filename = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%LOCALAPPDATA%\Dropbox\info.json");
```

When I run it in vs I get the path I need which is

> C:\Users\User-pc\AppData\Local\Dropbox\info.json

when published to IIS I get

> C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Dropbox\info.json

Comment: You should deploy that info.json file with the application to the APP_DATA folder, then read it from there.

Answer (score 1):

This is because IIS is not running under your user account. It is running under a system account. C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\ is the correct path for the IIS account.

You could set the user account on the IIS app pool to be your user (not great for secuirty, https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170(v=ws.10).aspx), or you could pass the correct path in another way (web.config maybe)?

Comment: The original question looks like a flawed XY problem to me: accessing a user's Dropbox application that is stored on a _server_ machine.

Comment: Could be, or could be deploying on his local machine.

Comment: @UweKeim I have a file on Dropbox that i need to use on multiple pcs , I use this method so i won't have to change every time the path in web.config.

Comment: you know this is looking at the server file system, not the user accessing file system?

Comment: @AndrewMonks Yes yes i'm aware of that

Comment: Why not simply use the Dropbox web app?

Answer (score 0):

%LOCALAPPDATA% is a user specific folder.
IIS doesn't use the same user as you when you run from VS.

In my opinion there are 2 solutions : 
 - Change the folder of this file to something more usual (Your web site folder, or something like D:\Dropbox\info.json)
 - Change the user IIS uses, but that's really not a good option